# APV pdf reader. Installation, Unzipping and Native library issues

Tags: android, shell, pdf, cygwin, mupdf

Ok so I've installed everything that should be needed in order for APV and/or MuPDF to work, but it still crashes.
I'm not very good at using shells to install programs and all that, but I did follow the instructions included in the readme files as good as i was able to.

When I try to run the program now (APV) It works fine until I try to open a pdf file, where I get the errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:442)
cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.startPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:403)
cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.onCreate(OpenFileActivity.java:169)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfview2: findLibrary returned null
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535) at cx.hell.android.pdfview.PDF.<clinit>(PDF.java:15)
```

I've installed everything in `D:\Android`, where i have the following

```
subfolders:
apache-ant-1.8.3
android-ndk-r7c
android-sdk
Cygwin
apv (containing : pdfview\jni\ libraries like freetype, mupdf, jpeg, openjpg etc. 
     also another version of android-ndk-r7c)
```

I've tried running all the build files included in the script documents like: build-native, scale-images, ndk-build
This is a screen dump from build-native just before it finishes.

```
successful stuff happening

cp: cannot create regular file '../jni/freetype/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '../jni/freetype/include/freetype/config/sed008052': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '../jni/freetype/include/freetype/config/sed007576': Permission denied
D:\Android\apv\pdfview\scripts\build-native.sh: line 31: gcc: command not found
D:\Android\apv\pdfview\scripts\build-native.sh: line 34: ../../scripts/fontdumpt: No such file or directory
```

I honestly have no idea how else to attack this and the tutorial at : http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/ReadMe.txt didn't do much for me. If anyone else have any experience using this then I'd really appreciate any help you could offer.

The application I'm making will be open source so by helping me you can get a good laugh at my code later on! :)

also, sorry for the shitty text but can't post images until i have 10 reputation

Thanks, Anders